# Core Data add relationship as unique constraint- iOS

Tags: ios, core-data, constraints, relationship

I'm developing an application with core data. There are many entities that uses relationships and in many of them they are the primary key.
I'm trying to use the unique constraints feature in the xcdatamodel but  there is no way to compile the project.
The error that Xcode shows is:
`cdtool cannot compile`.

It only happens with relationships, if I add an attribute in the constraints there is no problem.

I would like to know if I'm doing something wrong or the relationship cannot be a unique constraint.

**EDIT 1:**
[image: relationshipsandconstraints]

Comment: If possible, try to give picture of data model and relationships

Comment: I have edited with the data model.

Comment: still seems to happen in iOS11 :(

Comment: As far as I know you can't add relationship in constraints. Go to the entity `Articulo` and add a constraint there. You are adding it from `BodegonReg`

Comment: constraints field must be string type. So it can't be relationship. I know I am very late in replying. But still posting if some still have any confusion about it.

Answer (score 1):

`Articulo` is an entity, it's not the property you can set constraints.
You should select `Ariculo` and add constraint `ariculoId`(this is the proper of Articulo) to it to make `Ariculo` is unique. 
In your diagram, `arculo_id` is the relationship. You may not set constraint on it possible.

Think about if the relationship is `oneToMany`, what you should do?

**EDIT:**

Tested on Xcode 15, **no errors**, **BUT** it doesn't work.

See the image below.
`bar` is the `to-one` relation:

[image]

Here is the result.

[image]

Then we try to set `Bar`'s `name` as the constraint:
**Still not work!**

[image]

**So far, seems `To-One` has no uniqeness feature.**

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen when in the constraints you put the property of the object and not the object! For example if you put entity.attribute